# CosmosDB sort results by a value into an array

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've some CosmosDB documents like the following

```
{
  "ProductId": 1,
  "Status": true,
  "Code": "123456",
  "IsRecall": false,
  "ScanLog": [
    {
      "Location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.5957758,
          42.7111538
        ]
      },
      "TimeStamp": 201602160957190600,
      "ScanType": 0,
      "UserId": "1004"
    },
    {
      "Location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          13.5957907,
          42.7111359
        ]
      },
      "TimeStamp": 201602161246336640,
      "ScanType": 0,
      "UserId": "1004"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I order the query results by the TimeStamp property? I've tried using this query

```
SELECT c.Code, b.TimeStamp FROM c JOIN b IN c.ScanLog ORDER BY b.TimeStamp
```

but I receive this error

```
Order-by over correlated collections is not supported.
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JOINs with ORDER BY are currently not supported.

However, here is a user defined function (UDF) that will do the trick:

```
function sortScanLog (scanLog) { 
  function compareTimeStamps(a, b) {
    return a.TimeStamp - b.TimeStamp;
  }
  return scanLog.sort(compareTimeStamps);
}
```

You use with a query like this:

```
SELECT c.ProductId, udf.sortScanLog(c.ScanLog) as ScanLog FROM c
```

If you want the opposite sort order, simply swap the a and b. So, the signature of the compareTimeStamps inner function would be:

```
function compareTimeStamps(b, a)
```

Alternatively, you can sort client-side after the results are returned.

Comment: I don't think paging applies because the array we are sorting is a sub-element of the root document. You either get it all or none.

Comment: Sorry, Larry.  What I meant was that if the I'm sorting the data in LINQ when it in comes back, any concept of a continuation token goes out the window.  So the MaxItemCount won't help if I'm trying to do any paging and I have a JOIN.

Comment: Ahh LINQ. I use node.js so I'm not a LINQ user.

Comment: I don't think the sorting tool makes any difference, right?  If you're retrieving part of the data and only sorting it at the client, who knows what's in the next page?  To sort the results, you have to get all of it, and then you're not paging it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, ORDER BY clauses mixed with JOINs are not supported, the engine can look at indexed properties for JOIN operations but cannot re-order results based on the JOIN result.

You'd have to go with something like Larry offered or do the JOIN on the Query and the Sort by your own code once the results arrive, if you use C#, you can sort them with Linq for example.

Comment: Any news on supporting this kind or query?