# order by in sub document in DocumentDB

Tags: sql-order-by, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I have a json document like following with sub-document

```
[
  {
    "id": "73e799df-b7a5-7470-4f25-ee6c1811a5b2",
    "tblType": "search",
    "memberId": 2,
    "results": [
        {"prcnt": 89,"distance": 8867775.747141607},
        {"prcnt": 30,"distance": 11010216.470879028},
        {"prcnt": 96,"distance": 9128590.716183286},
        {"prcnt": 41,"distance": 9652043.937920697}
    ]
  }
]
```

i want to get the **'results'** tag data only in the query with order by **prcnt**

> SELECT top 10 m.results FROM m  join r in m.results where m.memberId=2
>   and m.tblType='search' order by r.prcnt

when i am executing the query, getting the error as follows..

> Order-by over correlated collections is not supported.

how to get the data per my requirement.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DocumentDB sort results by a value into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584755/documentdb-sort-results-by-a-value-into-an-array)

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further support?

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, I have checked this issue. Here are my understanding about this issue:

- If the `memberId` and `tblType` could locate the single document, then you could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584755/documentdb-sort-results-by-a-value-into-an-array):

**UDF**

```html
function sortByPrcntNumber (results) { 
  return results.sort(function(a,b){
      return a.prcnt-b.prcnt;
  });
}
```

**QUERY**

```html
SELECT value udf.sortByPrcntNumber(c.results)
from c 
where c.memberId=2 and c.tblType='search'
```

- If the `memberId` and `tblType` could retrieve multiple documents, I assumed that you could leverage **STORED PROCEDURES** as follows:

```html
function sample(top,tblType,memberId){
  var collection=getContext().getCollection();
  var isAccepted=collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    "SELECT value {\"prcnt\":r.prcnt,\"distance\":r.distance} from c join r in c.results where c.tblType='"+tblType+"' and c.memberId="+memberId+"",
    function(err,feed,options){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!feed||!feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody("no docs found");
        else {
           //order by prcnt
           var orderedFeed=feed.sort(function(a,b){
               return a.prcnt-b.prcnt;
           });
           //select top
           var topFeed=orderedFeed.slice(0,top);
           getContext().getResponse().setBody(topFeed);
        }
    });

    if(!isAccepted) throw new Error("The query was not accepted by the server.");
}
```

**Result**

[image]