# Sorting with UDF when using JOIN

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to retrieve data from a CosmosDB container. Essentially the data structure is like this:

```json
{
  "id": "123456",
  "customerCode": 123456,
  "data" : {
    "orderNumber": 222222,
    "customerOrderNumber": "orderNum",
    "customerNumber": 123456,
    "orderLines": [
      {
          "productCode": "123456",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With all the entries in this order table, I want to retrieve the inner order lines, but sort them by the 'productCode' attribute.

This is the current query:

```sql
SELECT l AS orderLine, c.data.orderNumber, c.data.customerOrderNumber, c.customerCode, c.data.orderDate 
FROM c 
JOIN l IN c.data.orderLines
WHERE c.customerCode=123456 AND l.status="23" 
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 30`
```

Unfortunately, CosmosDB doesn't allow this, as it throws "Order-by over correlated collections is not supported" if I try to just do a ORDER BY as you'd do in typical SQL.

Reading this, it can be worked around using a user defined function: [CosmosDB sort results by a value into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584755/cosmosdb-sort-results-by-a-value-into-an-array)

I'm not sure though, I can utilise it in my query with it's self join?

Tried this and a few other variations but it doesn't like it, as I guess it's not working with the array at this point. Also tried it in the actual JOIN clause but didn't work either.

```sql
select udf.sortByProductCode(l) as orderLine, c.data.orderNumber, c.data.customerOrderNumber, c.customerCode, c.data.orderDate 
from c
join l in c.data.orderLines 
where c.customerCode=123456 and l.status="23" 
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 30
```

Comment: So if document with "id" "123" has orderLines with productCode "A" and "C" and document with "id" "456" has orderLines with productCode "B" and "D" your desired results would be `(123,A), (456,B), (123,C), (456,D)`? Or you mean something different than that? If you *do* need that I suspect you might need to use analytical store for this

Comment: Yes you're correct. Currently we're sorting it in Java, but it doesn't really work because we're only sorting the subset of results with the LIMIT 30, rather than all of them. This means the pagination results are all wrong.

Other alternative is to retrieve all results and still do the sorting in Java which is less desirable. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> Retrieve the inner order lines, but sort them by the 'productCode' attribute.

**Explanation:**

- The `sortOrderLines()` UDF is called on the **orderLines** array in the data object of each document by the function `udf.sortOrderLines()`. The array is sorted according to the **productCode** values.
- Array containing only the **orderLines** elements with a status of "23". It selects the **productCode** values from each of these filtered order lines.
- **localCompare** is a JavaScript method used to compare two values based on their local specific order.

**Data in my container:**

- Container has multiple records, among those some records have the same `customerCode` and `status` and some are **unique.**

[image]

[image]

**Query I tried with:**

```sql
SELECT c.data.orderNumber,
c.data.customerOrderNumber, c.customerCode,
udf.sortOrderLines(
    ARRAY(SELECT  VALUE ol FROM ol IN c.data.orderLines WHERE ol.status  = "23")
) AS sortedOrderLines
FROM c WHERE c.customerCode = 123456
```

**UDF I used:**

```js
function sortOrderLines(orderLines) {
    return orderLines.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.productCode.localeCompare(b.productCode);
   });
}
```

**Output:**

- Total count of records is below:

[image]

- Below is the output in a sorted order after filtering with `customerCode` and `status`.

[image]